# Splitting org-file

Tags: org-mode

I'm currently using an org-file to organise absolutely everything. That includes personal stuff, work stuff, etc.

I'd like to separate a branch so that I can take it to the office with me and leave other (personal) branches aside.

Now, normally, I could split my org-file in two, add a link from one to the other, and add both to the agenda search list.

However, I'm using the sparse tress in the normal file buffer (not agenda) *a lot*, to get a 50K view of everything I'm tracking, including both personal and work stuff. I'm actually exporting the resulting tree to a PDF (whole buffer, only visible parts after filtering), and evaluating it carefully. This feature would not work if I split the files, unless I can somehow make org-mode understand that a separate file is meant to be treated as a subtree.

Is there any way to do this?

EDIT: Clarifies question

Comment: `#+INCLUDE` with `:minlevel` option is probably what you're looking for. https://orgmode.org/manual/Include-files.html

Comment: Well, that includes the whole file. That's going to have a huge history, which is bound to grow, and it'll include everything. I'm using filtered view and exporting only the visible part of the whole buffer, but that option inserts the whole included file in the PDF, without filtering it.

Comment: I've added extra info to clarify what I'm looking for.

Comment: From the page I linked earlier: `#+INCLUDE: "./paper.org::*conclusion" :lines 1-20`
   Include the first 20 lines of the headline named ‘conclusion’.